# confusing error occured when using tkinter listbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I've encountered a really confusing error when using self:

Here ive created two pages using tkinter with two different classes. One page displays employee info and the other allows users to add data into a listbox made on the main page(the window that displays data). Im trying to add info into the listbox but got an error `'NewEmployee' object has no attribute 'listbox'`.

Below you can see i am clearly using self. for the listbox i have made yet the error shows a different the class the listbox is not within???

```
class MainPageGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Jans Corp")
        self.master.configure(background='lightgrey')
        self.master.geometry("1200x800")

        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self.master,width=150, height=35)
        self.listbox.place(x=150, y = 130)

        @staticmethod
        def DisplayData(self):
        a = Database(self.master)
             for data in enumerate(a.ReadData()):
             self.listbox.insert(1, data) #getting error here
```

Class that lets users add emplyoee data using entry boxes and button.(not complete):

[Add Employee page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYitc.png)

```
class NewEmployee:
    def __init__(self, master): #Creating basic GUI to add employees

        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Jans Corp")
        self.master.configure(background="lightgrey")
        self.master.geometry("300x500")
```

I am confused as to why the complier says `NewEmployee` class has no "listbox" when ive created it in `MainPageGUI` and also used self.

if anyone would like to view the code: https://github.com/Sharjeel50/Database-System/blob/master/New%20Project1.py

Any help or explanation would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use `self.master` in `DisplayData`, remove the `@staticmethod` decorator, and include `self.master = master` in `__init__`.

Comment: ive used `self.master = master` for every window i need, ive also created separate classes for them.

Comment: @YouKnowMe You haven't used `self.master = master` in `MainPageGUI`

Comment: i forgot to add that it is not the complete class. ive only added what was needed in this example so people dont have to read through a lot of code.

Comment: @YouKnowMe I think the problem is that `self.master` hasn't been set when `self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self.master,width=150, height=35)` is called

Comment: it has been set as the listbox shows on the screen, the problem is when i hit a button to enter data into the listbox, the compiler gives me an error saying that there is no listbox in `NewEmployee` even though the listbox is in `MainPageGUI`

Comment: @YouKnowMe Regardless, you can't pass `self` into a `@staticmethod`

Comment: Ah i see, what can i use instead?, i took off `self.` before defining the listbox but still recieved an error `listbox is not defined`

Comment: @YouKnowMe I think you want to remove the `@staticmethod` decorator, but keep `self`. It looks like you're trying to use variables like `self.master` and `self.listbox` which require you to pass in `self`.

Comment: I have `@staticmethod` as im calling it from another class, im also using it so i dont have to make an instance of the class when i want to use the method somewhere else.. is there no other way around this?

Comment: @YouKnowMe I think it makes the most sense to make it an instance method.